# How to convert numbers to dates

Tags: python, datetime, integer, number-formatting, data-conversion

the emplyee number is composed of year and month and 3 digit control number how to know the number of years they works if we base on todays date? Employee1 201011003, eployee2 200605015

Comment: Have you tried datetime.datetime.strptime? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datetime library like this:

```
from datetime import date

date_str = '201011003'
year = int(date_str[0:4])
month = int(date_str[4:6])
d = date(year, month, 1)

year_delta = (date.today() - d).days // 365
print(year_delta)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.strptime` to read the date string into a `datetime` object. By subtracting two `datetime` objects you'll get back a `timedelta` object, which you can use to compute the years the employee has been there.

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_date(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s[:6], '%Y%m')
```

Examples

```
>>> get_date('201011003')
datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>> get_date('200605015')
datetime.datetime(2006, 5, 1, 0, 0)
```

Depending on the precision you want, you can approximate the number of years the employee has been there like

```
def get_years(s):
    start = datetime.strptime(s[:6], '%Y%m')
    now = datetime.now()
    return (now - start).days / 365.25

>>> get_years('201011003')  
9.527720739219713
>>> get_years('200605015')
14.03148528405202
```

Answer (score 0):

To get very accurate results, I suggest you to use the [dateutil package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/). It contains a super powerful function called `relativedelta` that is going to give you the years, months and days that have passed since the day you are interested in, considering leap years (instead of just days, as the `datetime.timedelta` does).

Also, just as [CoryKramer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61755481/7303434) did, we can use the `strptime` function to parse the date from the employee's codes you have.

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


employee = '201011003'
date_joined = dt.datetime.strptime(employee[:6], '%Y%m')
result = relativedelta(dt.datetime.today(), date_joined)

print('The employee has been working for {} years, {} months and {} days'.format(
    result.years, result.months, result.days))
```

**Outputs**

```
The employee has been working for 9 years, 6 months and 11 days
```